# ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup, cannot find where the problem is

Tags: latex

I'm getting a "! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup." error when I try to compile the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes,xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, natbib=true, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{CARRTEL.bib}
%\usepackage{scicite}

%\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}


%\usepackage{times}


\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}




\newenvironment{sciabstract}{%
\begin{quote} \bf}
{\end{quote}}




\title{Internship report} 




\author
{Manuel Thouillot, INSA Lyon}
}

% Include the date command, but leave its argument blank.

\date{}



\begin{document} 
\pagenumbering{gobble}
% Double-space the manuscript.

\baselineskip24pt



\maketitle 

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage


\begin{sciabstract}
Abstract
\end{sciabstract}


\section*{Presentation of CARRTEL}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Presentation of CARRTEL}

CARRTEL (Centre Alpin de Recherche sur les Réseaux Trophiques et les {\'E}cosystèmes Limniques, Alpine Research Center on Trophic Networks and Limnics Ecosystems) is an INRAE (Institut National de Recherche pour l'Agriculture, l'Alimentation et l'Environnement, National Research Institute on Agriculture, Nutrition and the Environment) research unit, split between a first location in Thonon-les-Bains (Haute-Savoie) and a second one on the Technolac campus between Chambéry and Aix-les-Bains (Savoie).\\





\newpage

\section*{Abstract}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Study site}

Lake Murten, also known as Lake Morat, is located in Switzerland in the Seeland region (the Three Lakes region), nested between the Alps and the Jura mountains on the Swiss Plateau.
It covers an area of 22.8 km$^{2}$ and possesses a volume of 0.55 km$^{3}$. Its surface altitude is 429 meters above sea level. The catchment area is considered to be 693 km$^{2}$. \\
Historically speaking, this region of the Swiss Plateau is rich in archaeological sites covering the last 10000 years.
%The very first traces of modern humans living in this area date back to 8,000 years before the Common Era (BCE) \cite{international__swiss_wetzikon_nodate}, but more extensive occupation really started around 4300 BCE \cite{bolliger_archaeological_2020, international__swiss_111_nodate, mondial_sites_nodate}. During the Neolithic, the Copper Age and the Bronze Age periods, settlements took the form of pile-dwelling communities on or near lake shores. Three such sites have been studied around Lake Murten, and show that human occupation of this particular area originated around 3500-3800 BCE \cite{international__swiss_greng_nodate, international__swiss_haut_nodate, international__swiss_murten_nodate}. \\
%During the Iron Age, as the population became more dense and centralized, human influence on the environment increased, as shown by the fact that large-scale deforestation and farming became practiced in the catchment area of Lake Murten.\\
%The Romans arrived in the region during the first century BCE. In particular, evidence collected around the modern town of Avenches shows that construction of the Roman city of \it Aventicum\/ began in the first decade CE \cite{blanc_avenches_2004}, and the city reached a peak population of about 20,000 inhabitants during the first century CE \cite{site_et_musee_romains_avenches_aventicum_nodate}.




\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography




\end{document}
```

I've looked for an extra }, I've also tried commenting out certain parts of the text to narrow down the location of the problem but I can't find it at all. I will admit that I am not the most experienced of LateX users and so it could be something relatively simple that I am not aware of.
What could be the root cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the full error message in the .log file

```
! Too many }'s.
l.38 }
      
You've closed more groups than you opened.
```

it will tell you where the extra `}` is:

```
\author
{Manuel Thouillot, INSA Lyon}
}
```

Comment: Even when I remove that one, I get the same error.
Could it have something to do with my .bib file, is there something I should check in there?

Comment: @MT74 It is considered rather rude to edit a question in a way which invalidates an existing answer. If you have a new problem, please ask a new question including a [mre] which reproduces your new problem.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of this, I will, thank you